# NextJS Dynamic URL parameters and User Friendly URL's

Tags: routes, next.js

I got so many questions below:

1. I'm generating "string parameters" on my URL's. But while I create them, they lose their user friendly types. For example my url must be: /category/books?groups=1,2,3,4 but router.push returns it to: /category/books?groups=1%2C2%2C3%2C4

My code is below:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const current_path = router.asPath
    const { sef } = router.query
    
    if(pickedProductGroup.length||pickedProductConcept.length){
      const groups = pickedProductGroup.join(',')
      const concepts = pickedProductConcept.join(',')

      const query = { group: groups, concept: concepts }
      const url = { pathname: '/category/[sef]', query }
      const urlAs = { pathname: '/category/' + sef, query }

      router.push(url, urlAs);
    }
  }, [pickedProductGroup, pickedProductConcept])
```

2. I cant rerender data, when I change my query strings.
   How can I trigger It everyrtime to rerender, If url param is changed. (the same parameters should render the same html of course, as It must be) But It renders /category/book even If my url returns to /category/book?group=1,2,3

   export const getStaticProps = async(context) => {
   const { sef, group, concept } = context.query;

   ```
      const products = await api.get(`/category/${sef}?group=${group}&concept=${concept}`)
      const web_main = await api.get('/header/web_main')
      return {
        props: {
          header_data: web_main.data.data,
          product_list: products.data.data,
          sub_categories: products.data.sub_categories,
          filters: products.data.filters,
        }
      }
    }
   ```

Comment: Please try to keep to one specific problem per question.

Comment: You can't access the query string from [`getStaticProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation). That method runs at build-time and has no access to the page request data. You'd want `getServerSideProps` for that.